# C# iterate on two dimensional array of buttons

Tags: c#, arrays, button

Im trying to iterate of a two dimensional array of Buttons like this

```
Button[,] buttonsArray = new Button[row,col];
foreach(Button button in buttonsArray)
{
   button = new Button();
}
```

but im getting the next error: "Error Cannot assign to 'button' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"

what im doing worng?

Comment: foreach iterator is readonly, so you cannot assign value to it.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler message says it all - you're trying to assign a new value to `button`, but the iteration variable (the one declared by a `foreach` statement) is read-only. A `foreach` loop can only be used to iterate over the existing content in a collection - it can't be used to *change* the content in a collection. (Note that if you change the data within an object referred to by the collection, that's not actually changing the value in the collection, which would just be a reference to the object.)

I suspect you really want something more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        buttonsArray[i, j] = new Button();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the value of the variable in a `foreach` loop. To circumvent this, you should use a regular `for` loop:

```
for(int i = row; i < row; i++)
{
    for(int j = col; j < col; j++)
    {
       buttonsArray[i, j] = new Button();
    }
}
```